# Backendless + Zapier. Create record with foreign relationship

Tags: json, zapier, backendless

I'm new to the world of Low Code app development, and so far I'm pulling my hair out.

I'm using a third party web app to submit JSON formatted data to Zapier via webhook, and then submit that to Backendless with codeless API that creates a record. I'm running into two issues that I can't figure out how to solve.

1. Backendless record creation with foreign key relationship. I'm creating a record in Table A, but that needs to have a relationship to Table B. I have it set up as such in Backendless, but in Zapier I don't see an option to populate the table_b_id in the Table A record I'm creating. What am I missing here?
2. After creating the Table A record, I want to create multiple records in Table C that are children of the Table A record. How on earth do I do this? With Python + SQL, I could do it in 2 minutes, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it the LowCode way using either Zapier or Backendless.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm totally stumped.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backendless actions for Zapier let you save/update/delete an object in a single table. These are distinct API operations. Creating a relationship is a separate API call that doesn't have a corresponding action in Zapier's Backendless integration. However, you can create a relation between the object you're saving and a related "parent" (or "child") table using an API event handler in business logic. It can be done with Java, JS or Codeless. The event handler you'd be creating is `afterSave`.
2. You can save multiple objects with a single call using Codeless. The simplest way to do this by using the `Bulk Create` block: https://prnt.sc/x6cwp4. The `objects` connector should be a list of objects to save in the table.